# pySerial setDTR not working well

Tags: python, pyserial, ftdi

At first I'm using PYthon 2.7.5, pySerial in last version for Python 2.7.x, Windows 7 (64) and FTDIFT232RL (so not real RS232 Serial port).
Just for the tests I created this code:

```
class cProduction:

    g_comPort_name = "COM1"
    g_comPort = 0

    # Instance of object -------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, portName):
        self.data = []
        self.g_comPort_name = portName

    # Main functions -----------------------------------------------------------
    def start(self):
        """ Open port, configure port, set pins of serial line to default state
        DTR true, RTS false """
        try:
            self.g_comPort = serial.Serial(
                port = self.g_comPort_name,
                baudrate = 9600,
                parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout = 10,
                dsrdtr = False,
                xonxoff = False,
                rtscts = False)

            if self.g_comPort.isOpen():
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return False
        return False
```

Main:

```
prod = cProduction("COM33")
if prod.start():
    print Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "Open" + Style.RESET_ALL
    while True:
        key = raw_input('key: ')
        if key == "R":
            prod.g_comPort.setRTS(True)
        if key == "r":
            prod.g_comPort.setRTS(False)
        if key == "D":
            prod.g_comPort.setDTR(True)
        if key == "d":
            prod.g_comPort.setDTR(False)

else:
    print Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + "Error while starting production module" + Style.RESET_ALL
```

RTS is working well but I have a problem with DTR. When I set DTR to False I can see on osciloscope that DTR was really set to low level, but after ~700ms it is return back to high level (without any interrupt from my side). In this time setDTR(False) is not working anymore. I have to first call setDTR(True) and after it setDTR(False) is working again (but again after 700ms it goes back to high level). The time 700ms is allwas the same.
I tried to change configuration of 'dsrdtr' or 'rtscts' but it was not helpful.

I have Qt application based on C++ which is working with my device correctly and now I'm just trying to rewrite it to Python so I'm on 100% sure that my device is correct.

**Edit:** I tried it with real RS232 COM port on my laptop and it is working corectly. So it seems that pySerial has a problem with Virtual COM port with FTDI chip...

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like a hardware or driver problem than a python issue.
Is there something connected to dtr ? It could be an hardware protection triggering because to much current is drawn.

You could try to use [logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [apimonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) on your application and on the Qt one to see if there is any difference.

Comment: I checked my GUI application base on C++ again and I also find this problem but not with timedelay about 700ms but about 2sec. So it is very strange and now it is look like a really problem with HW (the device) and with some lucky it was working. But first I have to check with HW department.